# Is it possible to put an RMarkdown chunk inside a table cell in a Rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I want to create a table inside a RMarkdown document that has a code chunk inside one of the table cells. I can put inline code using the `` symbols inside a table cell, but not an entire, multi-line code chunk.

For example, in-line code works fine to produce a markdown table:

```
header1 | header2
--------|--------
`code`  | text
```

But what if you want to put a code chunk in the lower-left corner instead of inline code? Say for example you have the following chunk and you want it in one of the table cells:

````
```{r}
2 + 2
3 + 3
```
````

I have no idea how to achieve this.

**Edit**: The html solutions provided by yifan are great! But, what about for pdf outputs? We discussed this in [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1655) on the rmarkdown github page. Best solution for now seems to be to use grid tables, like this:

````
+----+-----+
|col1|col2 |
+====+=====+
|``` |foo  |
|a   |     |
|b   |     |
|``` |     |
+----+-----+
````

This will work for code blocks, but not code chunks, which does not seem feasible without substantial changes to rmarkdown or knitr.

Comment: You can use `knitr::kable`, `formattable::formattable` or `DT::datatable`. These should be better alternative for creating tables.

Comment: I tried using these alternatives, but none of them support code chunks. If you put a code chunk in a data frame and try to render it using something like knitr::kable(), it just prints out the code chunk as a string.

Comment: Probably you should use bootstrap grids instead of tables, if you want to the display tabular code chunks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677438/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-grid-layout-in-rmarkdown. Or you can write pure HTML table instead of markdown table

Comment: One way could be printing HTML to PDF.

Comment: That was my next thought. If I can get the printout to look reasonable, that might just be the solution for now!

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1: Bootstrap table in HTML

````r
<table class='table'>
<tr> <th>column1</th> <th>column2</th> <tr>
<tr>
<td>
```{r}
print("a")
```
</td>
<td>
```{r}
a = runif(10)
print(a)
```
</td>
<tr>
</table>
````

[image]

## Method 2: Bootstrap Grids

````r
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">Column 1</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Column 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
```{r}
print("a")
```
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
```{r}
a = runif(10)
print(a)
```
</div>
</div>
</div>
````

[image]